# Вопрос от подлежащего к сказуемому

Tags: синтаксис

Здравствуйте. Меня интересует, какой вопрос от подлежащего к сказуемому можно задать в предложении **У меня есть отец**? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подлежащее обозначает предмет речи, сказуемое  - то, что говорится о предмете  речи. Предмет речи в Вашем предложении - отец. Задаю вопрос: что говорится об отце? Что он есть. Есть - сказуемое.

Comment: А что является предметом речи в предложении "У меня нет отца"? А ведь сказуемое "нет" говорит о том же предмете, что и в исходном предложении. Что-то здесь недоступное моему пониманию, нелогичное. Или мы будем опираться только на формальные грамматические признаки (я про именительный падеж подлежащего)?

Comment: Да, в традиционном (структурном, формализованном, школьном...) синтаксисе- так. Есть и другие направления синтаксиса - семантический, коммуникативный - там по-другому.

Answer (score 1):

У меня нет отца. Слово "отца"  стоит  в родительном  падеже, это дополнение. Грамматической  основой  предложения является  слово  "нет"-сказуемое.Нет  кого? отца. Безличное предложение.
У меня  есть отец. Слово "отец" стоит в именительном  падеже. Кто ? Отец  --подлежащее. Что о нем говорится? отец  ЕСТЬ, есть --сказуемое.
Как видите, у слова  "отец" в  этих  предложениях  разные формы, и соответственно разная синтаксическая  функция.

Answer (score 0):

Предметом речи в предложении "У меня нет отца" является отсутствующий отец :) Сказуемым "нет" это подтверждается.

Comment: Скорее,  предмет речи здесь - я. Обо мне говорится, что я не имею отца. Но подлежащее должно быть в именительном падеже.